# Differ between selected and entered tags in Select tags mode

Tags: antd

I am using a `<Select mode="tags" />` and need a way to find out which new tags were added in the box.
As an Example, I initialize the Select with the option values 1,2,3,4 coming from an api.
I now add option '2' as tag by clicking it and add '5' as a new value by writing.

How to recognize this 5 value as new added?